# Algorithm for removing multiple elements from a Red-Black tree

Tags: c++, red-black-tree

Is there an algorithm that allows to delete multiple nodes in RB or the only algorithm to delete nodes from RB is to do it in a way:
1. Delete one and
2. if necessary fix tree

Answer (score 3):

If more than half the nodes are being deleted, you can throw away the existing tree and build a new one in less time, since insertion and deletion have the same cost.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no constraint that says the tree must remain balanced while you are doing a multiple node deletion, it seems reasonable to me that you could fix the tree after doing multiple deletes.

The purpose of balancing the tree after each deletion is to make sure the delete operation is consistent in its computational cost. If you do not require deletes to be consistent in this fashion, you could write your delete algorithm differently. The fixup operation will be a more lengthy computation than after just one delete, though. It will also likely be a more complicated one, too.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't make sense. If you delete nodes from the tree without fixing the tree, you will be left with danging pointers to left and right branches.

Comment: I think Phillis meant that the pointers would be connected after node delete, but it wouldn't be rebalanced until the entire LL of nodes-to-be-deleted was removed.

Comment: I think this might be a bad approach regardless - the complexity of rebalancing a tree after multiple removals would likely be excessively higher than the sum of single deletes.  Its been awhile since I have worked with these though.

Comment: @reuscam: It depends on the numbers... the cost of rebalancing the tree is no worse than O(n), where n is the number of remaining elements, since in the worst case you can simply rebuild the tree from scratch, and the elements are already sorted. Rebalancing at each step takes time O(d*log(N)), where d is the number of deletions and N is the original number of elements in the tree. So if a lot of elements are being deleted, then d*log(N)*K might be much bigger than n*k (where k & K are the constant factors involved), which may make a rebuild worthwhile.

Comment: reuscam, you had the intent of my comment correct. i don't necessarily recommend doing it this way either - tree rebalancing isn't that simple of a problem to begin with. parsing the tree to rebalance multiple nodes isn't something i would want to attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in a data structure called [TeardownTree](https://github.com/kirillkh/rs_teardown_tree). It supports `delete_range` operation that works in `O(k + log n)` time, where `n` is the initial number of items in the tree and `k` is the number of items deleted (and returned to the caller). Full disclosure: I am the author.

I have to emphasize that the data structure does not support the `insert` operation, but is optimized for `clone` and `delete_range`. I have written up an informal [description of the algorithm](https://github.com/kirillkh/rs_teardown_tree/blob/master/delete_range.md). With all the optimizations the code is now significantly different from that document, but it should be enough to grasp the idea.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this problem was to create a linked list of nodes to be deleted and to use the standard deletion method on them in succession. I would be interested to know if there is a better algorithm for mass deletion.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a Treap instead of a Red-Black tree, since balancing the tree in various scenarios seems easier with a Treap v/s a Red-Black tree. I'm have the same problem as you, but with Treaps. https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20495/algorithm-to-bulk-delete-nodes-from-a-treap

Am unsure if the expected height bounds remain valid post bulk-deletion (algorithm mentioned in the question).